# How to make a mysql server publicly acessible with MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I am developing an app that I want to let include server interaction. I have installed MySQL server and MySQL Workbench. I am able to query my data base locally from Java. such as local host. but when I change the query correctly, to reference the IP of my server and not "localhost", I am unsuccessful both on my server and separate machine. I have pinged my server from my another machine successfully. I have configured user accounts on MySQL workbench in almost every way possible. I have done a lot of googling with little success.

I am 19 and just starting to learn SQl now. It'sn ot a big part of my project. I am sorry if this sounds like a basic question, but google has gotten me no where and I am really eager to publish my app xP . So I would really appreciate the help or even a basic guide as to what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you will need to GRANT access from remote computers. Here's a guideline: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, this is because you did not yet assign user permissions for remote computers. You'd have to use something like tyhe following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON myDatabase.* 
TO myUser@’mycomputers.ip.address’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘my_password’;
```

There's a more extensive guide here:

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/

Comment: the first line of code, is not working on cmd. I come from mac. do I have to change directory? # mysql -u root -p

Comment: @Jared - I know absolutely nothing about Macs, but you would have to navigate to the folder where mySQL is installed. That line is intended to log into MySQL so you can issue commands against it. The GRANT command then allows you to specify what permissions you assign to users from other machines.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.

Comment: @Jared - Just let us know if there's anything else you'd need :)

Comment: Sorry I thought I understood what to do. I am on windows. I tried changing directory to the various folders named MySQL, including the hidden one in ProgramData, no luck. I am unsure of what command I should be entering before  # mysql -u root -p, and is it supposed to be in command prompt or MySQL shell? Thanks for the kind help, Schmitz

Comment: @Jared - You will need to find the path where you installed MySQL Server (typically C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin). You should either add that to your PATH, or maneuver there from a shell (using CD). Then you can login to MySQL using `mysql -u root...`, etc. The # there indicates you're doing this from a shell/command prompt

Comment: @Jared - You're welcome. If the answer helped you, please remember to mark it as the answer so future visitors can see the resolution. Thanks :)

Comment: FYI, MySQL Workbench has a `Privileges` page in the `Users` section that would allow to assign such rights, without going to comman dline.